# Replace %p with %pK in linux kernel code

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I am maintaing a linux driver and I want to replace all %p in driver with %pK. For doing this i used following command.

```
grep "%p[^K]" -Rl . | xargs sed -i 's/%p[^K]/%pK/g'
```

It fails in below case.

```
%p-%p --> %pK%pK (hyphen is removed)
```

Please suggest proper regular expressionfor sed command to work.

Comment: I think you are looking for a way to assert that `%p` is not followed by `K` and then replace... one way is to use `perl` with lookarounds... ex: `echo '%p-%p' | perl -pe 's/%p(?!K)/%pK/g'`

Comment: @Sundeep I am trying to do same, but I want to make changes in all files in all position where %p is present ( not %pK). So is there any way to do same with `sed`. I tried following but did not work.
`grep "%p[^K]" -Rl . | xargs sed -i 's/%p(?!K)/%pK/g'`

Comment: try `echo '%p-%p' | sed -E 's/%p([^K]|$)/%pK\1/g'`... and I would suggest `grep -RlZ '%p[^K]' | xargs -0 sed -i -E 's/%p([^K]|$)/%pK\1/g'` to prevent issues with filenames containing special characters... also I hope you are trying this out on test folders instead of directly applying changes on actual files.. you can do that once you have a working solution

Comment: sed doesn't have lookaround regex, that is why I suggested perl..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sed replacement in the question would remove any characters after a `%p`, not just dashes, since the `[^K]` is part of the matched string. You can work around that by capturing the character after `%p` with (escaped) parenthesis, and putting it back with `\1`. In `sed`:

```
$ echo '%p %p %pK' | sed 's/%p\([^K]\)/%pK\1/g'
%pK %pK %pK
```

Though you might want to use `[^a-zA-Z]` or similar just in case you were to use other modifiers for `%p`.

Answer (score 0):

Following command did magic for me

```
for fname in $(grep "%p[^K]" -Rl .); do perl -pi -e 's/%p(?!K)/%pK/g' $fname; done
```

Thanks Sundeep, Your comment helped a lot. :)

Comment: That _is_ an answer, though it would be much better with an explanation, so it would be independent of the comments.